# How can i redo a GET request with request module if i get an error?

Tags: node.js, http, callback, get, request

this is my code:

```
var Request = require("request");

Request({url:url, qs:propertiesObject}, function(err, response, body) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200 ) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
  });
```

I don't need to console.log the error but i need to redo my GET request if err is true.
I'm using nodejs and request module to do the GET.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Request = require("request");

var options = {url:url, qs:propertiesObject}
function handleResponse(err, response, body) {
    if(err) {
      Request(options, handleResponse);
    }
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200 ) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
}

Request(options, handleResponse);
```